# Adding a new functionality to TAB for Clojure mode

Tags: emacs, clojure, tabs

I know that TAB wants to be smart in Emacs.  However it is not smart enough for my taste.  And because it is "smart", it seems to be complicated to extend.

I'd like TAB in Clojure mode to act exactly as it acts, *excepts* when I'm at the first parenthesis of a `defn, defmacro`, etc. which is located at column 0.

When it's there, I want it to call *hs-toggle-hiding* from *hs-minor-mode* instead.

However I'm getting crazy trying to get it to work.

I first tried to modify the shortcut assigned to TAB so that, when in Clojure mode only, it would first call my function which would then call *indent-for-tab-command* but changing the TAB shortcut seems to be amazingly complicated.  And since that Emacs already planned for the case where modes can register their TAB function in lisp-indent-function, I was hoping to modify *clojure-indent-function*, which says :

```
(defun clojure-indent-function (indent-point state)
  "This function is the normal value of the variable `lisp-indent-function'.
```

However this function is apparently only called *when the cursor is inside the function*.  Not when the cursor is on the first '(' of, say, "(defn ...").

How can I can get TAB to call `hs-toggle-hiding` when in Clojure mode and when pointing at column 0, on a parenthesis?

I don't want this to affect org-mode nor any other mode.  Just Clojure mode.

Comment: What is `TAB` bound to in `M-x describe-mode`?

Answer (score 3):

The general answer would be:

```
(eval-after-load 'clojure-mode
  '(define-key clojure-mode-map [tab] 'my-tab-command))
```

And the definition, as you described:

```
(defun my-tab-command (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (and (zerop (current-column)) (eq (char-after) ?\())
      (hs-toggle-hiding)
    (indent-for-tab-command arg)))
```

Answer (score 3):

`clojure-indent-function` is an implementation of `lisp-indent-function`, which is *not* supposed to indent but rather to *calculate* indentation. It can be called at any time by any code which is interested of possible indentation, so we certainly don't want to hook our desired <kbd>TAB</kbd> behavior into this place.

Given the smartness of <kbd>TAB</kbd> which might not be what you want at an interesting point, it may be better to rebind `TAB` to put our logic in front of *all* possible smartness:

```
(defun clojure-hs-tab (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (and (<= (current-column) 1)
           (save-excursion
             (beginning-of-line)
             (looking-at "\(")))
      (hs-toggle-hiding)
    (indent-for-tab-command arg)))

(define-key clojure-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'clojure-hs-tab)
```

I took liberty to modify your requirement and allow column 1 too,
because that's where hs-toggle-hiding places the point after hiding. Don't you want to unhide by a second <kbd>TAB</kbd> keypress?

The next level of "tab smartness" is the `indent-line-function`
variable. That's what gets called when a *completing-or-indenting* tab
was determined to *indent* and not to complete. There is a strong
reason not to use it here: `indent-line-function` may be called
multiple times for indenting *regions*. Even if we decide that we want
to override just the *indent* behavior of indenting and completing
<kbd>TAB</kbd>, it's better to advise `indent-for-tab-command`
(advising globally and checking `major-mode` to do what we want only
in that mode).

Comment: Oh thanks a lot.  It's all new for me and it's amazing: there seems be endless ways to do things in Emacs so it's not  always easy to find where to start when you're beginning : )